# How can I export my reviews, votes, questions and answers from Amazon?

Tags: amazon, export

I wonder whether there is any way to export my reviews, votes, questions and answers from Amazon.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this site posted elsewhere and tested their demo: http://app.feedcheck.co/amazon-review-exporter 
(I have no affiliation with them)

Comment: Including essential content of the link would be more helpful.